# The sequence 1/(n-1) is apparently unbounded yet convergent. What am I missing here?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

For the sequence 1/(n-1): x1 is undefined. I think that makes the sequence unbounded. However I can prove from definition that the sequence is convergent. And there is the theorem that all convergent sequences are bounded. So what am I missing?

Comment: Having $x_1$ undefined just means your sequence starts at $2$ (or a higher index). If you define $y_n = x_{n+1}$, you get a sequence with the exact same limit behavior, but now defined for all $n\geq 1$. Is that sequence bounded? Then so is the original.

Comment: An undefined term in not actually in the sequence.    Only defined terms are in the sequence.  And all terms in the sequence have finite value.

Comment: If $a_1$ is not a number then $a_1,a_2,\ldots$ is not a sequence of numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a_n = \frac{1}{n-1}$ where $n\ge 2$.

It converges to $0$ as $n\to \infty$. It is bounded by $1$.

Note that the sequence is not defined for $n=1$ as you will encounter with the zero division problem.